# неправильный ответ на тесте в коде на питон

Tags: python

Я писала код по следующей задаче:

> Путь в летнюю школу лежит через болото. Чтобы пересечь болото, мальчик Миша будет прыгать по кочкам, которые выстроены вдоль прямой и пересекают это болото. Миша еще маленький, поэтому он может прыгнуть либо на следующую кочку, либо через одну или сразу через две. К сожалению, некоторые кочки неустойчивы, поэтому много школьников уже засосало в болото. На их опыте Миша знает, что из *n* кочек есть ровно *m* прыгнув на которые он увязнет в болоте. Помогите Мише понять сможет ли он добраться до летней школы
>
> Миша начинает путь на кочке с номером *1*, заканчивает  на кочке с номером *n*.
>
> **Входные данные:** В первой строке записаны два целых числа *n* и *m* — общее число кочек и количество неустойчивых соответственно. Во второй строке через пробел записаны *m* различных целых чисел *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ... , a<sub>m</sub>* (*1 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ n*) — номера неустойчивых кочек (в произвольном порядке).
>
> **Выходные данные:** Выведите «YES», если Миша может добраться до кочки с номером n , наступая только на устойчивые кочки. В противном случае выведите «NO».
>
> **Примеры:**
>
> ```
> входные данные
> 10 5
> 2 4 8 3 6
>
> выходные данные
> NO
>
>
> входные данные
> 10 5
> 2 4 5 7 9
>
> выходные данные
> YES
> ```

Написала по ней код:

```py
n, m=map(int, input().split()) 
l=list(map(int, input().split()))
l.sort()
if (1 in l) or (n in l):
    print("NO") 
else:
    ans="YES"
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        if l[i+1]==l[i]+1 and l[i+2]==l[i]+2:
            ans="NO" 
            break 
    print(ans)
```

Но проверяющая система на 8 тесте пишет ошибку выполнения. Помогите пожалуйста исправить!

Comment: исправила, а есть еще какие-то ошибки

Comment: Я ошибок не вижу. А они есть?

Comment: теперь ошибка выполнения на тесте 8, я отправляла код из вопроса

Comment: Какая ошибка? Как сформулирована? Может быть не проходит по времени?

Comment: так и написано "Ошибка исполнения на тесте 8"

Comment: Могли бы Вы подробнее сказать об ошибке, потомучто на первый взгляд я не вижу прям таких проблем в Вашем коде. Та и 2 прикреплёных к вопросу теста он проходит корректно..

Comment: в том то и дело, что сама не знаю, в чем ошибка, может данные на 8 тесте как-то не так ввелись... наверное ошибка компиляции

Comment: Какие даны ограничения на *n* и *m*?

Comment: 1≤n≤109, 0≤m≤3000